# How to remove frozen entry in Nautilus file/copy transfer dialog?

Tags: 13.04, nautilus, freeze, transfer

Sometimes it happens that an item freezes/hangs in the Nautilus file/copy transfer dialog.

- It is not possible to abort the progress (You can click the icon, the button gets disabled, but nothing happens).
- If you close the dialog and re-open it, there is still the broken file transfer item in it.

How to solve this issue or can someone provide a workaround?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a hang after I started copying from a network drive and my machine went into suspend while copying was still going on. Closing Nautilus from the panel context menu did not help, after restarting nautilus the copy dialog was still hanging at the same position.

What did help was `xkill`:

```
Alt+F2 -> xkill
```

The cursor is now a small cross, and the process of the next window that you left-click on is killed. Make sure you have the window visible. Right-click aborts xkill.

Comment: Hmm, now I can not re-open the same network drive window again, which I also killed. But it worked, the copy dialog disappeared and after starting a new copy-past operation, the frozen copy job also disappeared. So I accept the answer.

Comment: Feel the power...

Answer (score 3):

xkill is not a good tool for this job. What xkill does is kill the connection Nautilus has to the X server. It's true that this will usually end the process, but you don't always want to count on that. You can open the System Monitor and end the process or just open a terminal and type in

```
killall nautilus
```

Comment: use: `killall nautilus && (nautilus &)`